# How Do I Set Task as preLaunchTask in .code-workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a multi-root workspace with launch configurations and tasks. The tasks run fine on their own, but they don't run when added as a preLaunchTask. VS Code throws the error "Could not find the task".

oving them to a tasks.json file is not an option for me.

Here's the relevant information from my .code-worspace file

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "App",
            "path": "app"
        },
        {
            "name": "API",
            "path": "api"
        },
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch App",
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder:App}",
                "url": "http://localhost:3000",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder:App}/src",
                "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                  "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
                }
              }
        ]
    },
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "npm",
                "script": "start",
                "label": "npm: start",
                "detail": "react-scripts start",
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder:App}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but this only happens if `type` = `npm`.

Change:

```json
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "start",
```

to:

```json
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "npm start",
```

Comment: I had it fixed already, but I double-checked and that is in fact how I got it to work.